# Best way to cut huge shape into tiles?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a large shape which is used as a giant map which is moved when a character moves (the character stays in center of stage at all times).

Now as the map is huge I want to cut the map into tiles that only are displeyed when they are inside the stage area.

My question is if there is a smart way of cutting the map into smaller tiles of the same sizes or do i need to select each tile by myself?

The shape/map is inside a symbol. And the thing is that the map is too big to animate, tgerefore to improve performance i only want to show the tiles currently between x=0 and x = 780
And between y=0 and y=400.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority #1 is absolutely to not even create the graphical objects for what's off-screen.  Create all the data and everything for gameplay purposes, but do not associate every tile with a graphical object.  Only create enough graphical objects to represent what's on-screen at any one particular moment, and associate them with whatever's on-screen at the beginning; then when the player moves, simply change which gameplay tiles those graphical objects are associated with.  This will keep you from running out of memory and doing other stuff like that very quickly.

You seem to be implying that the gameplay maps are logically divided into tiles.  In that case you could do something like this:

```
var x:int = 0;
var y:int = 0;

for (var i:int = firstColumnInFocus; i < firstColumnInFocus + widthRange - 1; i++)
{
    for (var j:int = firstRowInFocus; j < firstRowInFocus + heightRange - 1; j++)
    {
        tileGraphics[x][y].tile = level.tiles[i][j];
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

As far as creating the logical tiles for the actual gameplay datastructures and stuff goes, just create a 2D array of tile or space objects that have whatever you need in them, and make sure the positions of elements in the array represent their geographical positions.

I'm not completely sure though whether this is what you're talking about.  In some ways it sounds like you're talking about a level that's already designed as a collection of tiles, and in other ways, it sounds like you're talking about taking a single sprite and simply using tiles as a way to approximate how much of it should be on screen.  It sounds to me personally like you're doing some of both, more or less, but your strategy should probably depend somewhat on what's really happening.

Comment: Thanks. I have already drawn a map in Flash. I was just wondering whether it is "enough" to store each tile in a symbol - only showing the parts of the map within the stage.

Comment: But would it be sufficient to put all of the symbols/tiles into one big symbol (the entire map). Hide the ones off-screen (outside the stage)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using symbols.  As far as I can tell, for the gameplay data, you should be good to go; the graphical hiding just needs to be done through object-pooling.